# D'où vient l'expression « Comme c'est » ?

Tags: grammaire, expressions

J'ai vu des phrases françaises commençant par *Comme c'est*, qui se traduit (approximativement) par l'anglais *how* ; par exemple :

> Comme c'est triste. (*How sad.*)

Pourquoi cette formulation, et pas le plus simple *Comment triste* ? Est-ce la formulation courante, et est-elle utilisée avec de nombreux autres adjectifs ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pour la première partie de la question :
*Comment triste ?* ne se dit pas en français, du moins, pas que je sache. C'est une de ces expressions qui ne s'exprime pas avec les mêmes mots que l'équivalent anglais.

Pour la deuxième :
La formulation « Comme c'est [adjectif] » est plutôt courante et apparaît dans les dictionnaires (par exemple le *Larousse* et *Le Petit Robert*). Dans ces expressions, le *comme* est un adverbe exclamatif d'intensité, utilisé comme le serait un *si*, un *tellement* ou, au Québec, un *donc bien*. 
Il s'utilise avec la plupart des adjectifs, par exemple :

> Comme c'est blanc ! (après la neige)
>   Comme c'est beau !
>   Comme c'est horrible !

Mais pas tous, par exemple :

> Comme c'est amoureux !

On peut aussi l'utiliser avec certains verbes, ou il faut conjuguer le verbe *être* :

> Comme ça brille !
>   Comme ça pue !
>   Comme ils sont amoureux ! / Comme ils s'aiment !

Answer (score 3):

1. "Comment est-ce triste?" serait une question, or "How sad/Comme c'est triste" est une affirmation.
   L'expression "Comment est-ce triste" reste cependant maladroite. "Comment triste" n'a pas de sens. On peut cependant demander "Trouvez-vous cela triste?", la réponse étant oui ou non. Même la question "Comment trouvez-vous cela?" ne peut pas avoir comme réponse "Comme c'est triste", mais plutôt "Je trouve cela triste"/"Triste"/"C'est triste".
2. Comme c'est triste équivaut à "Comme cela est triste". Le CNRTL indique :

> Comme est un adverbe exclamation d'intensité
>
> Comme + être + adj.

On peut très bien dire: "C'est triste". En ajoutant "comme" devant, on insiste sur le faite que cette tristesse est intense. (Cela marque en général que la personne se sent impliquée)

Comme n'a rien à voir avec "comment" qui concerne les moyens.

Autres exemples:

> Comme c'est dommage
>
> Comme c'est beau
>
> Comme c'est bizarre
>
> Comme c'est bien
>
> ...

Comment: Ça ne répond pas vraiment à la question.

Comment: Honnêtement, je ne vois pas quoi dire d'autre :P

Comment: @M'vy peut-etre ajouter une explication pour *comment triste* en place de *comme c'est triste* - est-ce une expression courante et/ou valide?

Answer (score 3):

Ce n'est pas une expression.

L'un des sens du mot *comme* est « à quel point », « combien ».
C'est ce *comme* là qui est utilisé ici.

Comment: Mais d'où vient ce sens ?